# how to set size of image within an iframe using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, iframe

I have an iFrame that contains an image.I need to set size of the image to fit into the iFrame. How do I add css property(height/width) to the image accessing its id.

**here is my code:**

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="50" width="150" id="liveAgent_iFrame" src="" style="padding-left: 10px; float:left">
  <img id="liveagent_button_offline_57317000000007n" src="" style="border: 0px none;">
</iframe>
```

**and here is my css to it:**

I have set the css propert through the id of the img tag.

```
 #liveAgent_iFrame #liveagent_button_offline_57317000000007n {
        width: 136px;
        height: 34px;
 }
```

Kindly suggest a way to set the image size within the iFrame. Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't add width and height to img tag like this <img id="liveagent_button_offline_57317000000007n"  src="xyz.gif"  height="34" width="136">

Comment: But this id is dynamically generated.The img tag is added through a (url) src of an iFrame. I need to override the css of the img element added to the iFrame.So i need to fetch the element and then modify its css.(height and width).